# LMDE2 does not work on my laptop after being installed from Live CD/DVD

Tags: debian, linux-mint, boot, grub, lmde

I have installed LMDE 2 on my Samsung laptop and when I try to start the system, I get this:
[image: Couldn't find OS]

I have to insert the LiveCD in order to start the system. When I finally use the LiveCD, I can see the menu and select the option to start from Hard Disk or Live CD:
[image: Live CD Menu]

In order to stop using the LiveCD, I extract it from my laptop and select the "Boot from local drive" option and the problem persists:
[image: Error]

I have to use the LiveCD until the GRUB menu is showed and finally I can select the OS I want to use.
[image: GRUB menu]

After selecting the first option, I can extract the LiveCD and work normally.

How can I solve this?

I have researched this and some people have said that it is necessary to copy those files (chain.c32 and vesamenu.c32) from CD to /usr/lib/syslinux/ but it doesn't work for me.

Is there any other option? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Boot completly from live cd (do not boot from hard drive!) and mount your hard drive to /mnt dir.

First of all check out path to vesamenu\menu files in your syslinux.cfg. Cfg file must be somewhere like /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg.
You should see something like `DEFAULT menu.c32` or `UI menu.c32` or vesamenu, it doesn't matter right now. If you dont see one of this lines then add them.

Then go to `/usr/lib/syslinux/bios` and copy `libcom32.c32`, `libutil.c32`, `menu.c32`, `vesamenu.c32` to boot directory of your hard drive. In some cases you can find this files in another directory like `/usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios`

Reboot and check out, system must to load without errors!

Good luck!

P.S. Also you can to install grub :)